# query for to read all the data of all keys except a specific one from Firebase Database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("company_emp");
```

Query?

I  want to pass it to FirebaseRecyclerAdapter as a one of the parameter in 4

```
company_emp:
         :         
         .USER_01:
         :         .email: "dsfsdfd"
         :         .user_id:"USER_01"
         :         .name:"don"
         :      
         :         
         .USER_02:
         :         .email: "dsfsdfd"
         :         .user_id:"USER_02"
         :         .name:"pen"
         :            
       .USER_03:
         :         .email: "dsfsdfd"
         :         .user_id:"USER_03"
         :         .name:"pen"
         :
```

So here i want to avoid USER_03 child.  what is the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("company_emp");
Query q=mDatabaseReference.orderByChild("user_id").limitToFirst(2);
```

This will give you user_01 and user_02

Add this in your database to user_01 and user_03:

```
   .email: "dsfsdfd"
   .user_id:"USER_03"
   .name:"pen"
   .num: "0"
```

add this to user_02:

```
 .email: "dsfsdfd"
   .user_id:"USER_03"
   .name:"pen"
   .num: "1"
```

`orderbyChild("num").equalTo("0")` //will give you user_01 and user_03

Comment: if i want to like except USER_02, then what will be the query ?

Comment: you can't do that, these are the queries: limitToLast, limitToFirst, startAt, endAt, equalTo @ThofiqAhmed. If you want only user_01 then u can do `orderByChild("user_01").equalTo("don")` . check the edit

Comment: that is, i too know